# Issue with setTo method in HtmlEmail for setting mail to multiple recipient

Tags: java, apache-commons-email

We have a module which will send reminder mail. We are using `apache commons email` library for sending mail. We have no issue if we send mail only one email address using `addTo` method of `HtmlEmail`, but we are encountering exception when we are trying to send the same mail to more than a user using `setTo` which accepts `Collection`. 
Even `commons mail` javadoc mentioned that this method is to send mail to a group of email address but surprisingly its not working.
Is there any workaround to solve this problem or hint to proceed with right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure, that your Collection contains only objects of the expected Type? Exerpt from the JavaDoc for [setTo(java.util.Collection)](http://commons.apache.org/email/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#setTo%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Set a list of "TO" addresses. All elements in the specified Collection
>   are expected to be of type java.mail.internet.InternetAddress.

Providing source code or exceptions for your problem would make it easier to help you to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: oops. Actually I tried to pass a list of toAddress string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can then iterate over your list of email Strings and add them via the http://commons.apache.org/email/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#addTo(java.lang.String) method.